# Azure creating VM from image using a monitoring webpage - authentication error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure subscription and an image I created.

I wrote some typescript code to a monitoring webpage that will allow users from the organization to spawn more instances of this image (first stage).

I'm using the default active directory, and have created a new user "admin" that has both "Application Administrator" and "Cloud Application Administrator" (does it really need both?).

I'm having an issue with the authentication.
The error I'm getting is:

```
Error creating VM: RestError: The client '<clientID>' with object id '<clientID>' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write' over scope '/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/Azure-test_group/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/myVM' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials. 
 {
  "name": "RestError",
  "code": "AuthorizationFailed",
  "statusCode": 403,
  "request": {
    "url": "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SubscriptionID>/resourceGroups/Azure-test_group/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/myVM?api-version=2023-03-01",
    "headers": {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "accept": "application/json",
      "accept-encoding": "gzip,deflate",
      "user-agent": "azsdk-js-arm-compute/21.1.0 core-rest-pipeline/1.12.0 Node/v16.17.0 OS/(arm64-Darwin-21.6.0)",
      "x-ms-client-request-id": "<id>",
      "authorization": "REDACTED",
      "content-length": "324"
    },
    "method": "PUT",
    "timeout": 0,
    "disableKeepAlive": false,
    "streamResponseStatusCodes": {},
    "withCredentials": false,
    "requestId": "<Id>",
    "allowInsecureConnection": false,
    "enableBrowserStreams": false
  },
  "details": {
    "error": {
      "code": "AuthorizationFailed",
      "message": "The client '<clientID>' with object id '<clientID>' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write' over scope '/subscriptions/<SubscriptionID>/resourceGroups/Azure-test_group/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/myVM' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
    }
  },
  "message": "The client '<clientID>' with object id '<clientID>' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write' over scope '/subscriptions/<SubscriptionID>/resourceGroups/Azure-test_group/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/myVM' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
}
```

my code files look as follows:

1.

```
// pages/api/azure-test/index.tsx

import { useState } from 'react';

interface AzureVm {
    InstanceId: string;
    PublicIpAddress: string | null;
}

const TestPage = () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [vms, setVms] = useState<AzureVm[]>([]);
    // Function to handle creating a new Azure VM
    const handleCreateInstance = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);

        try {
            const response = await fetch('/api/azure-create-instance', { method: 'POST' });
            if (response.ok) {
                console.log('VM created successfully!');
                // fetchVms(); // Refresh the vm list after creation
            } else {
                console.error('Failed to create vm.');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('An error occurred:', error);
        } finally {
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Test Page</h1>
            <button onClick={handleCreateInstance} disabled={isLoading}>
                {isLoading ? 'Creating VM...' : 'Create VM'}
            </button>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>VM ID</th>
                        <th>Public IP Address</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {vms.map((vm) => (
                        <tr key={vm.InstanceId}>
                            <td>{vm.InstanceId}</td>
                            <td>{vm.PublicIpAddress || 'N/A'}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
};

export default TestPage;
```

2. 

```
// pages/api/azure-create-instances.ts

import { ComputeManagementClient, VirtualMachine } from '@azure/arm-compute';
import { DefaultAzureCredential } from '@azure/identity';

const subscriptionId = process.env.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID!;
// console.log('subscriptionId: ', subscriptionId);
const resourceGroupName = 'Azure-test_group'; // Replace with your resource group name
const vmName = 'myVM'; // Replace with your desired VM name
const location = 'westeurope'; // Replace with your desired location
const vmSize = 'Standard_DS1_v2'; // Replace with your desired VM size

const createVM = async () => {
    try {
        // Authenticate using DefaultAzureCredential
        const creds = new DefaultAzureCredential();
        // console.log(creds);
        const computeClient = new ComputeManagementClient(creds, subscriptionId);

        // Define VM parameters
        const vmParams: VirtualMachine = {
            location,
            hardwareProfile: {
                vmSize,
            },
            storageProfile: {
                imageReference: {
                    publisher: 'Canonical',
                    offer: 'UbuntuServer',
                    sku: '18.04-LTS',
                    version: 'latest',
                },
            },
            osProfile: {
                computerName: vmName,
                adminUsername: 'myAdmin', // Replace with your desired admin username
                adminPassword: 'myPassword123!', // Replace with your desired admin password
            },
            networkProfile: {
                // Network configuration
            },
            // Other VM configurations
        };

        // Create VM
        const result = await computeClient.virtualMachines.beginCreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, vmName, vmParams);
        console.log('VM created:', result);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error creating VM:', err);
    }
};

createVM();
```

my .env file has the following Ids: `AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET, AZURE_TENANT_ID, AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID` But I think the authentication still fails.

I am not sure if it is something I should change in the Azure portal, or in the code.
Important to note, so far I only gave the secret ID (AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET) but still did not use anywhere the secret "value".

any help / guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assigned the user "**Application Administrator**" and "**Cloud Application Administrator**" role and when I tried to create the VM, I got the same error:

[image]

> The client '' with object id '' does not have authorization to perform action  'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write' over scope
> '/subscriptions//resourceGroups/Azure-test_group/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/myVM' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

The error usually occurs if the user doesn't have sufficient permissions to perform the action.

**Note** that: To create VM the user must have **`Virtual Machine Contributor`** role assigned in the subscription level.

The "Application Administrator**" and "Cloud Application Administrator" doesn't include `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write` permission which is needed to create VM.

The **`Virtual Machine Contributor`** role have the permission:

[image]

**To resolve the error**, assign **`Virtual Machine Contributor`** role to the user like below:

[image]

After assigning the role, you will be able to create the VMs.

**Reference:**

[Azure built-in roles - Azure RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#virtual-machine-contributor)

Comment: thanks. I did as you suggested, but I think for whatever reason my credentials are not even recognised - in the error message i keep getting the "client" and "object id" are the same (client 'X' with object id 'X' does not have authorization to perform .../write ...)  and I am not sure where is the problem occuring. Did you have a similar problem before?

Comment: Yes but after assigning the virtual machine contributor role i am able to create VM

Comment: Can you paste the screenshot of assigning role?

Comment: this actually does resolve the problem. The issue was that i added the users i have, instead of adding the app. once the app was added (both "Virtual Machine Contributor" and "Classical Virtual Machine Contributor") it pass the authentication. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[[image: adding role assignment1]

Above is a screen shot of adding the role assignment, below is me checking that the roles exist.

[image]

Comment: Can you try deploying the VM now?

Comment: And are you using Azure AD Application to create the VM if yes then assign Virtual Machine Contributor role to the Service Principal.

Comment: no i get the same error.
by assigning the role to the Service Principal do you mean this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http ?
should I not do it on the portal? I'm confused by this

Comment: Can you paste the snip of assigning role to the Service Principal? You can do it via Portal too